# Snowflake Tasks - Visualizing hierarchy

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

Snowflake allows to create a chain of tasks using `AFTER` syntax.

> [CREATE TASK](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html)
>
> ```
> AFTER string
> ```
>
> Specifies the predecessor task for the current task. When a run of the predecessor task finishes successfully, it triggers this task (after a brief lag).
>
> **This parameter enables defining a simple tree of tasks; i.e. a set of tasks organized by their dependencies.** In this context, a tree is a series of tasks that start with a scheduled root task and are linked together by their dependencies.

Assuming we have the following:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
CREATE WAREHOUSE Developer WITH WAREHOUSE_SIZE = 'XSMALL' 
       WAREHOUSE_TYPE = 'STANDARD';
CREATE SCHEMA TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task1 WAREHOUSE = Developer SCHEDULE = '10 minute'
AS SELECT system$wait(20);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task2 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task1
AS SELECT system$wait(30);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task3 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task2
AS SELECT system$wait(60);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task4 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task1
AS SELECT system$wait(20);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task5 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task1
AS SELECT system$wait(30);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task6 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task3
AS SELECT system$wait(40);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task7 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task5
AS SELECT system$wait(50);

CREATE OR REPLACE TASK task8 WAREHOUSE = Developer AFTER task5
AS SELECT system$wait(30);
```

The goal is to get graphical representation of tasks for quick overview or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to generate the graph using built-in [Viewing Task History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-tasks.html)

> Task graphs depict executions of a root task and child tasks in DAG format. You can perform the following actions with task graphs:
>
> - Display task information, including status by root task and selected child task.
> - Examine task graphs, which are drawn from parent to child tasks.
> - Select task elements to view additional details.

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake supports: [TASK_DEPENDENTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/task_dependents.html) table function:

> This table function returns the list of child tasks for a given root (i.e. parent) task in a simple tree of tasks.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, NAME) AS TASK_NAME, PREDECESSOR
FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_DEPENDENTS(TASK_NAME => 'task1',
                                              RECURSIVE => TRUE ));
/*
TASK_NAME        PREDECESSOR
TEST.TEST.TASK1 
TEST.TEST.TASK2 TEST.TEST.TASK1
TEST.TEST.TASK4 TEST.TEST.TASK1
TEST.TEST.TASK5 TEST.TEST.TASK1
TEST.TEST.TASK3 TEST.TEST.TASK2
TEST.TEST.TASK7 TEST.TEST.TASK5
TEST.TEST.TASK8 TEST.TEST.TASK5
TEST.TEST.TASK6 TEST.TEST.TASK3
*/
```

Using the idea of **"Diagrams as Code"** and **[Mermaid](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/)** we could generate the following flow chart:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, NAME) AS TASK_NAME, *
   FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_DEPENDENTS(
                   TASK_NAME => 'task1', RECURSIVE => TRUE )) 
                             -- here goes task name
), rec AS (
   SELECT 
      0 AS lvl, cte.TASK_NAME, cte.PREDECESSOR,
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        'ROOT{.} -- "SCHEDULE: <schedule>;CONDITION: <condition>" --> <root>'
       ,'<schedule>', COALESCE(cte.SCHEDULE, '<none>'))
       ,'<condition>', COALESCE(cte.CONDITION,'<none>'))
       ,'<root>', cte.TASK_NAME)  AS GRAPH_ENTRY
   FROM cte 
   WHERE PREDECESSOR IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rec.lvl + 1 AS lvl, cte.TASK_NAME, cte.PREDECESSOR,
          REPLACE(REPLACE('<T1> --> <T2>'
          ,'<T1>', cte.PREDECESSOR)
          ,'<T2>', cte.TASK_NAME) AS GRAPH_ENTRY
   FROM rec
   JOIN cte ON rec.TASK_NAME = cte.PREDECESSOR
)
SELECT 'graph TD' || CHAR(13) || 
       LISTAGG(CHAR(9) || GRAPH_ENTRY || CHAR(13), '') 
               WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lvl) AS flow_chart
FROM rec;
```

We will get the following output:

```
graph TD
    ROOT{.} -- "SCHEDULE: 10 minute;CONDITION: <none>" --> TEST.TEST.TASK1
    TEST.TEST.TASK1 --> TEST.TEST.TASK2
    TEST.TEST.TASK1 --> TEST.TEST.TASK4
    TEST.TEST.TASK1 --> TEST.TEST.TASK5
    TEST.TEST.TASK2 --> TEST.TEST.TASK3
    TEST.TEST.TASK5 --> TEST.TEST.TASK7
    TEST.TEST.TASK5 --> TEST.TEST.TASK8
    TEST.TEST.TASK3 --> TEST.TEST.TASK6
```

It could be visualized using [Mermaid-live-editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit):

[image]

**[Mermaid Flow chart - LiveDemo](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#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)**

---

**Extras: It could be also used to visualize history of execution using Gantt diagram:**

Enabling all tasks:

```
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK8 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK7 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK6 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK5 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK4 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK3 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK2 RESUME;
ALTER TASK TEST.TEST.TASK1 RESUME;
SHOW TASKS;
```

Generating Gantt diagram:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS('.', DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, NAME) AS TASK_NAME,
  QUERY_START_TIME,
  COMPLETED_TIME,
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, QUERY_START_TIME,  COMPLETED_TIME) AS DURATION_SEC,
  TASK_NAME || ':' || TO_VARCHAR(QUERY_START_TIME, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') 
            || ',' || DURATION_SEC || 's' AS GRAPH_ENTRY,
  s.gantt || LISTAGG(CHAR(9) || GRAPH_ENTRY || CHAR(13), '') 
         WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY QUERY_START_TIME) OVER() AS graph
FROM TABLE(information_schema.task_history(
           scheduled_time_range_start=>'2021-05-16 07:00:00.000'::TIMESTAMP_LTZ))
,LATERAL(SELECT REPLACE(
'gantt
    title Task execution
    dateFormat YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
    axisFormat  %Y-%m-%d %H:%M
    section RunId=<run_id>
'
,'<run_id>'
,RUN_ID)
) s(gantt)
WHERE STATE = 'SUCCEEDED'
  --AND RUN_ID = x
ORDER BY scheduled_time;
```

Output:

```
gantt
    title Task execution
    dateFormat YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
    axisFormat  %Y-%m-%d %H:%M
    section RunId=xxxxxx
    TEST.TEST.TASK1:2021-05-16 07:13:45,20s
    TEST.TEST.TASK5:2021-05-16 07:14:06,31s
    TEST.TEST.TASK4:2021-05-16 07:14:09,21s
    TEST.TEST.TASK2:2021-05-16 07:14:15,30s
    TEST.TEST.TASK8:2021-05-16 07:14:51,34s
    TEST.TEST.TASK7:2021-05-16 07:14:51,50s
    TEST.TEST.TASK3:2021-05-16 07:15:01,60s
    TEST.TEST.TASK6:2021-05-16 07:16:15,40s
```

[image]

**[Mermaid Gantt diagram Live Demo](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#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)**

---

### ADDENDUM - support for mutltiple predecessors:

[Tasks: DAG Support — Preview](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/2022-06.html#tasks-dag-support-preview)

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT CONCAT_WS('.', DATABASE_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, NAME) AS TASK_NAME,
          TRIM(sub.VALUE) AS PREDECESSOR, t.SCHEDULE, t.CONDITION
   FROM TABLE(INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TASK_DEPENDENTS(
                   TASK_NAME => 'task1', RECURSIVE => TRUE )) t
                             -- here goes task name
   ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(COALESCE(PREDECESSOR, ''), ',') sub
), rec AS (
   SELECT 
      0 AS lvl, cte.TASK_NAME, cte.PREDECESSOR,
      REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        'ROOT{.} -- "SCHEDULE: <schedule>;CONDITION: <condition>" --> <root>'
       ,'<schedule>', COALESCE(cte.SCHEDULE, '<none>'))
       ,'<condition>', COALESCE(cte.CONDITION,'<none>'))
       ,'<root>', cte.TASK_NAME)  AS GRAPH_ENTRY
   FROM cte 
   WHERE PREDECESSOR = ''
   UNION ALL
   SELECT rec.lvl + 1 AS lvl, cte.TASK_NAME, cte.PREDECESSOR,
          REPLACE(REPLACE('<T1> --> <T2>'
          ,'<T1>', cte.PREDECESSOR)
          ,'<T2>', cte.TASK_NAME) AS GRAPH_ENTRY
   FROM rec
   JOIN cte ON rec.TASK_NAME = cte.PREDECESSOR
)
SELECT 'graph TD' || CHAR(13) || 
       LISTAGG(CHAR(9) || GRAPH_ENTRY || CHAR(13), '') 
               WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY lvl) AS flow_chart
FROM rec;
```

Sample:

```
-- extending scenario in question
ALTER TASK task6 ADD AFTER task7;
ALTER TASK task6 ADD AFTER task8;
```

Output:

[image]